# secretOrPrivateKey must have a value in jestjs

Tags: jwt, nestjs, backend

I'm encountering an issue with nestjs.
i've defined my `auth.module.ts` like this:

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserModule } from 'src/user/user.module';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';

@Module({
  imports: [
    UserModule,
    JwtModule.register({
      global: true,
      secret: process.env.JWT_CONSTANT,
      signOptions: { expiresIn: '1h' },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [],
  controllers: [AuthController],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

and this is my `auth.service.ts`

```js
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { UserService } from 'src/user/user.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    private userService: UserService,
    private jwtService: JwtService,
  ) {}

  async signIn(
    email: string,
    userPassword: string,
  ): Promise<{ accessToken: string }> {
    const user = await this.userService.getUser(email);

    if (user.password !== userPassword) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }

    const payload = { sub: user.id, username: user.pseudo };

    return {
      accessToken: await this.jwtService.signAsync(payload, {
        secret: process.env.JWT_CONSTANT,
      }),
    };
  }
}
```

as long as I'm passing the secret in the auth service, it works perfectly, but by following the documentation, I shouldn't have to pass it here as I've already defined it in the module. I checked if the `process.env.JWT_CONSTANT` and it's not, I even replaced it by a hardcoded string "toto" and still had the issue.

And finally, this is the app module:

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { AuthController } from './auth/auth.controller';
import { AuthService } from './auth/auth.service';
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { UserService } from './user/user.service';
import { PrismaService } from './prisma.service';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController, AuthController],
  providers: [AppService, AuthService, UserService, JwtService, PrismaService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use registerAsync

```js
JwtModule.registerAsync({
  inject: [ConfigService],
  useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => ({
    secret: config.get('JWT_CONSTANT'),
    signOptions: {
      expiresIn: '1h',
    },
  }),
})
```